# Tikz matrix without outer border

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I have want to draw square-tile in tikz like the following picture:
[image: iwant]

I use matrix styles and put thing in.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{sq} = [rectangle, minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw=black ]
\tikzstyle{sqvec} = [matrix,draw=black,thick] 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [sqvec] (v7) at (2.5,4) {
\node[sq] {}; &\node[sq] {}; &\node[sq] {}; \\
\node[sq] {}; &\node[sq] {}; &\node[sq] {}; \\
};      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is what I got:

[image: igot]

I want to **get rid of the second outer border** and **make inner border have equal thickness with outer border**.

Comment: `\tikzstyle{sqvec} = [matrix,thick]`, but for more nice result you need to tweek your nodes' settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

for above image the solution given in my comment should be replaced with more sophisticated way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={minimum size=7mm, draw, outer sep=0pt},
             nodes in empty cells,
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth
             ]
{
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```